# performance issues with groovy getProperty() method

Tags: groovy

suppose that i have a method which has the signature like

def myAction(objet,String propertyName);

i just want to retrieve the property value from objet, i wrote two versions

version 1: I construct the getter method and invoke it on objet

```
    original = propertyName
    prefix = original.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()
    suffix = original.substring(1,original.length())
    methodName = new StringBuilder('get').append(prefix).append(suffix).toString()
    value = domain.metaClass.invokeMethod(objet,methodName,null)
```

version 2: I use directly getProperty method supplied by GroovyObject

```
value = objet.getProperty(propertyName)
```

Witch one has better performance?

thinks : )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can test it to find out [using GBench](https://github.com/gperfutils/gbench)...

I came up with 4 different methods:

```
@Grab( 'org.gperfutils:gbench:0.4.2-groovy-2.1' )

// Your 'version 1' method
def method1( object, String propertyName ) {
    original = propertyName
    prefix = original.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()
    suffix = original.substring(1,original.length())
    methodName = new StringBuilder('get').append(prefix).append(suffix).toString()
    assert 'tim' == object.metaClass.invokeMethod(object,methodName,null)
}

// Your 'version 2' method
def method2( object, String propertyName ) {
    assert 'tim' == object.getProperty( propertyName )
}

// The same as method 1, but more Groovy
def method3( object, String propertyName ) {
    assert 'tim' == object.metaClass.invokeMethod( object, "get${propertyName.capitalize()}",null)
}

// And get the property with the Groovy String templating
def method4( object, String propertyName ) {
    assert 'tim' == object."$propertyName"
}
```

We can then define a class we're going to test:

```
class Test {
    String name = 'tim'
}

def o = new Test()
```

And then we can run a benchmark over all 4 different versions:

```
benchmark {
    'method1' {
        method1( o, 'name' )
    }
    'method2' {
        method2( o, 'name' )
    }
    'method3' {
        method3( o, 'name' )
    }
    'method4' {
        method4( o, 'name' )
    }
}.prettyPrint()
```

On my machine, this prints out:

```
Environment
===========
* Groovy: 2.1.6
* JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.25-b01, Oracle Corporation)
    * JRE: 1.7.0_25
    * Total Memory: 255.125 MB
    * Maximum Memory: 1095.125 MB
* OS: Mac OS X (10.8.4, x86_64)

Options
=======
* Warm Up: Auto (- 60 sec)
* CPU Time Measurement: On

         user  system   cpu  real

method1  1630       7  1637  1648
method2   429       1   430   435
method3  1368       1  1369  1378
method4   629       1   630   637
```

So, the fastest is the `getProperty` one, followed by the `object."$propertyName"` one, followed by the shorter version of your `version 1` method, followed by your original (and slowest) version 1 code

However, I'd argue that `method4` is easier to read, and so you have to ask whether it is worth the slight dip in performance